# Can't deploy to google apps engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a little application which is working fine when testing is on localhost.

But when I want to deploy it to google app engine server, I have thoses errors :

```
Compiling module org.magnetik.semola.Org_magnetik
   Validating newly compiled units
      Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Finding entry point classes
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Users/magnetik/git/semola-rdf/org.magnetik/src/org/magnetik/semola/client/RDFServlet.java'
         [ERROR] Line 13: No source code is available for type javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 16: No source code is available for type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 16: No source code is available for type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 25: No source code is available for type com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 25: No source code is available for type com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 37: No source code is available for type java.io.ByteArrayInputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Unable to find type 'org.magnetik.semola.client.RDFServlet'
         [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
         [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
```

Usefull files (I think) are here : http://pastebin.com/zuELG18u

Comment: Can you check the gwt.xml if it has all needed modules. For example for using GWT XML, you need to inherit XML module like: <inherits name="com.google.gwt.xml.XML" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your project use GWT for the client side? Your deployment is failing when it is trying to do a special GWT compliation step.

I believe your problem is that your `RDFServlet` class is part of a GWT module, which is not what you are intending.

The default Eclipse project for GAE comes preconfigured to work with GWT.  The package is structure in the example is like this:

```
client/    <--- GWT code (for client side, compiled to JavaScript)
shared/    <--- Code necessary on both the client and server
server/    <--- Server side code
```

When GWT compiles client/ down to JavaScript, it needs the full source of all its dependencies, and there are many classes that should not be referenced. However, it seems that you have a servlet (`RDFServlet`) in the "client" package.

You probably want to either disable GWT in your project, or move `RDFServlet` into a package that is not part of a GWT module. (For example, if you are using the Eclipse sample project, `Servlets` would be put somewhere under the 'server' package.

Comment: I wasn't using any GWT tools, disabling GWT tools feature in Eclipse has done the trick. Thanks !!